# ES6 Dynamic Imports using Webpack and Babel

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules

I've been using Webpack for my ES6 JS project and has been going well until I started to play with dynamic imports.

What I had that worked (router.js):

```
import { navigo } from "Navigo"; // router
import { clients } from "Controllers/clients.js";

const navigo = new Navigo();

navigo_router.on({
  '/clients': () => {
    clients.init();
  }
});
```

But the more pages/routes I add, the more imports get stacked up in the head of the module. This is a relatively large app and I have a lot of pages/routes to add and therefore I need to load them dynamically to reduce the size of the initial page load.

So, following [Webpack's documentation for dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-), I tried the following which loads the controller module ***only*** when the relative route is called:

```
import { navigo } from "Navigo"; // router

const navigo = new Navigo();

navigo_router.on({
  '/clients': () => {
    import("Controllers/clients.js").then((clients) => {
      clients.init();
    });
  }
});
```

But saving this in my editor resulted in a Babel transpiling error; **SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level**, and `clients.init()` is not being called when tested in browser.

After a bit of reading, I discovered I needed a [Babel plugin](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack) to transpile dynamic `import()` to `require.ensure`. So, I installed the plugin using the following command:

```
npm install babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack --save-dev
```

And declared the plugin in my `babel.rc` file

```
{ "plugins": ["dynamic-import-webpack"] }
```

After installing the plugin, the transpiling error disappeared and checking my transpiled code I found that the dynamic `import()`s has in fact been changed to `require.ensure` as expected. But now I get the following browser errors when testing:

```
Error: Loading chunk 0 failed.
Stack trace:
u@https://<mydomain.com>/js/app.bundle.js:1:871
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' 0.app.bundle.js:1
Error: Loading chunk 0 failed.
```

I didn't understand why it was referencing `0.app.bundle.js` with the `0.` prefix, so I checked my output/dist folder and I now have a new file in there called `0.app.bundle.js`:

```
0.app.bundle.js      1,962bytes
app.bundle.js        110,656bytes
```

I imagine this new bundled file is the dynamically imported module, `clients.js`.

I only added dynamic importing to that one route and have left all the other routes as they were. So, during testing, I can view all routes except that one `/clients` route that now throws the above errors.

I'm totally lost at this point and hoped somebody could help push me over the finish line. What is this new file `0.app.bundle.js` and how am I supposed to be using it/including it in my application?

I hope I've explained myself clearly enough and look forward to any responses.

Comment: That particular error is almost always from the server serving HTML when something else (JSON, JavaScript, CSS, etc) was expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to fix my own problem in the end, so I will share what I discovered in an answer.

The reason the chunk file wasn't loading was because Webpack was looking in the wrong directory for it. I noticed in the Network tab of my developer console that the the chunk file/module was being called from my root directory `/` and not in `/js` directory where it belongs.

As per Webpack's documentation, I added the following to my Webpack config file:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
  publicPath: "/js/", //<---------------- added this
  filename: 'app.bundle.js'
},
```

From what I understand, `path` is for Webpack's static modules and `publicPath` is for dynamic modules.

This made the chunk load correctly but I also had further issues to deal with, as `client.init()` wasn't being called and yielded the following error:

```
TypeError: e.init is not a function
```

To fix this, I also had to change:

```
import("Controllers/clients.js").then((clients) => {
  clients.init();
});
```

To:

```
import("Controllers/clients.js").then(({clients}) => {
  clients.init();
});
```

Note the curly braces in the arrow function parameter.

I hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: I have tried what you mentioned but get below error:  `bundle.js:106 Uncaught (in promise) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 0 failed.
(error: http://localhost:3000/js/src/app/0.bundle.js)`.   Can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60056219/how-to-use-dynamic-import-in-typescript-with-webpack-application

Answer (score 0):

For debugging, you need to do

```
import("Controllers/clients.js").then((clients) => {
    console.log(clients);
});
```

maybe working

```
import("Controllers/clients.js").then((clients) => {
    clients.default.init();
});
```